# Get Visual Studio's Version in the SDK

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-addins, visual-studio-extensions

I've been updating some of my extensions to make them compatible with with Visual Studio 2012. Most of them I've simply had to change the vsixmanifest file to report it is compatible with 2012.

However, the one I'm currently working on requires a slight change of code. Instead of having 2 separate extensions, I'd prefer to detect the version of Visual Studio and use that fact to run the correct logic.

However, I haven't found a good way to detect what version of Visual Studio the extension is running in.

What's the best way to find it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Detect the Visual Studio version inside a VSPackage](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11082436/detect-the-visual-studio-version-inside-a-vspackage)