# How to read the version of an installed VSPackage

Tags: c#, .net-4.5, vspackage

I want to check the version of the currently installed VSPackage to notify the users if his version is outdated. I don't want to upload my extension (yet), so I can't use the built-in update feature.

How can I read the version of my extension that is specified in the vsixmanifest file?

Comment: @michaelrmcneill: no duplicate! I want the version of my installed VSPackage and not the version of Visual Studio!

Comment: @SimonMourier: I know how I can read/edit/view it in Visual Studio. I would like to know how to read the version when the extension is running. Similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11082436/detect-the-visual-studio-version-inside-a-vspackage?rq=1 but not the Visual Studio version.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a function like this:

```
    public static Version GetExecutingAssemblyVersion()
    {
        var ver = FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);

        // read what's defined in [assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("1.2.3.4")]
        return new Version(ver.ProductMajorPart, ver.ProductMinorPart, ver.ProductBuildPart, ver.ProductPrivatePart);
    }
```

Comment: The VSPackage is executed inside Visual Studio. Your code will only give me the Visual Studio version.

Comment: Have you tested it? Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly gets the assembly that contains the code that is currently executing.

Comment: I stand corrected! But this gives me the DLL version and not the version I specified in the vsixmanifest file.

Comment: You should state what you want exactly (the Vsix manifest version) in your question, like I asked initially.