# VSIX - Minor visual studio version

Tags: visual-studio-extensions, vsix

Does somebody know if/how it is possible to obtain the minor Visual Studio version that is currently running, from within a VSIX extension?

I've already found the following property, but we would like to have the more detailed version number (more parts). https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/envdte._dte.version?view=visualstudiosdk-2017

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you may want the level like `X.Y.Z` instead of `X.0 or X.Y`. (e.g: VS2017-15.9.13=>15.9=>15.0).

**Sergey's** great answer can help you resolve the issue if the format `X.Y` is enough for you. But if you want to get the full details like `VS version+version number`, you can consider using registry key.

**For VS2015 and earlier versions** you can see [this vsx document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/internals/detecting-system-requirements?view=vs-2015&redirectedfrom=MSDN#detecting-visual-studio-editions) and this [similar issue](https://superuser.com/questions/1426668/how-to-detect-visual-studio-edition-programmatically), you can try to use RegistryKey to access the info you want from `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\DevDiv\vs\Servicing\<version>`.
[image]

But since the installation experience of VS2017 has changed for the vs `installer.exe`. We can't access the version details about VS2017 and VS2019 under that registry key any more.

**For VS2017 and VS2019**, I find we can access the related info at `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VSCommon\15.0 or 16.0\SQM\PIDs\`.

[image]

If in the machine only has one edition of VS2017 and VS2019, you can use code like this to get details:

```
            DTE dte = Package.GetGlobalService(typeof(DTE)) as DTE;
            string version = dte.Version;
            string editon = dte.Edition;

            RegistryKey key = Registry.CurrentUser;
            RegistryKey pidsKey = key.OpenSubKey("Software\\Microsoft\\VSCommon\\" + version + "\\SQM\\PIDs\\", true);
            string[] instances = new string[10];
            instances = pidsKey.GetSubKeyNames();

            RegistryKey instanceKey = key.OpenSubKey("Software\\Microsoft\\VSCommon\\" + version + "\\SQM\\PIDs\\" + instances[0], true);
            //read the details about VSManifestID
            string versionInfo = instanceKey.GetValue("VSManifestID").ToString();
```

The versionInfo's format see here: VisualStudio/15.9.13+28307.xxx (Apart from `VSManifestID`, you can also use `VSChanelID`...)

But this **won't work** if you have more than one edition of same VS version in PC.(VS20xx community and enterprise in same machine). In this situation you have to add much more judgement logic with the help of `dte.Version and dte.Edition`.

Comment: This SO answer seems to do the similar thing but without explicit work with the registry:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/55039958/2893207

Answer (score 4):

The following code shows "16.0.29306.81 D16.2" in my VS 2019:

```
var shell = (package as System.IServiceProvider).GetService(typeof(Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.SVsShell)) as Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.IVsShell;
object ver = null;
shell.GetProperty((int)Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.__VSSPROPID5.VSSPROPID_ReleaseVersion, out ver);
System.Windows.MessageBox.Show(ver.ToString());
```

Comment: What language is this?  I am trying in C# for a .NET Framework extension for VS 2022, and it is complaining about the syntax of `package as System.IServiceProvider` (the name package does not exist in the current context).

Comment: @JayImerman This C# code needs to be called from a Visual Studio extension, and package is your Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Package object.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to find the minor part of VS is to get version information from the file "devenv.exe":

```
var devenvInfo = FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo(dte.FullName);
return new Version(devenvInfo.FileMajorPart, devenvInfo.FileMinorPart);
```