# How to detect visual studio version from within an visual studio extension

Tags: visual-studio, vs-extensibility

I'm writing a Visual Studio extension supporting Visual Studio 2017 and 2019. Since In some circumstance I need to know, which version the extension is currently installed in, to adjust the extensions behavior accordingly. I searched the [visual Studio API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/?view=visualstudiosdk-2019), but up to now I was not able to find out the current version. Its now imported what kind of version I get e.g VS 2017 or 15.9.17 or this internal build version. Anything would be fine. has anybody a hint?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57867761/vsix-minor-visual-studio-version

Comment: Your answer sounds promising. I will  give it a try.